# focusing the text field

Tags: java, javascript

How to focus the calender after selecting the date from calender..

I am selecting the date and calender is also closing but  after that focus is missing.

Please help me on this issue..

Regards

Sk

Answer (score 1):

It seriously depends on the calendar implementation you use.

If the calendar is drown by Java tag try to seek the `onchange` attribute and set it to:

```
document.getElementById('calendarFieldId').focus();
```